# watir/ruby waiting for iframe to exist

Tags: ruby, selenium, iframe, watir

I have a problem waiting for an iframe to exist on page after entering a date range and I would rather not use sleep. I am using ruby/watir

I have tried solutions like this -

```
wait_until(10, "iFrame has not loaded") do
  @browser.iframe(id: "dtl00_DP1_content").exists?
end
```

but this simply returns this error - Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: no such window

So how do I wait for an iframe that does not yet exist please?

Comment: You only want to check whether Iframe appears? Or are you going to perform some operation inside the iframe? If you are going to perform some operation inside the iframe like `@browser.iframe(name: "something").text_field(name: "username").set 'raja'` then watir automatically waits for the iframe first, In case, if it doesn't appear, then it would throw the following error `timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::IFrame: located: false; {:id=>"something", :tag_name=>"iframe"}`

Comment: You would only get the NoSuchWindowError if you switched to another window that got closed. You need to switch back to an active window first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether you only want to wait for an Iframe, If you want to perform any operation on an element which is present in the iframe, then you could do as I mentioned in my comment.

```
@browser.iframe(name: "something").text_field(name: "username").set 'raja'
```

Or If you still wait for an `iframe` to appear, then write the following code

```
@browser.wait_until { @browser.iframe(id: "dtl00_DP1_content").exists? }
```

The above code waits for 30 seconds, but If you want to increase the time to wait, then write the following code, the following code would wait fo 50 seconds.

```
@browser.wait_until(timeout: 50) { @browser.iframe(id: "dtl00_DP1_content").exists? }
```